# Whonix and anonsurf

Tags: whonix

Am using parrot os and I have whonix set up in a VM all the two. But I still run anonsurf whiles connected to the whonix. Will there be any problem or is it a bad thing to do. Thank you

Comment: What is anonsurf? That doesn't sound like something that the Tor Project produces.

Comment: Might result in Tor over Tor? https://www.whonix.org/wiki/DoNot#Prevent_Tor_over_Tor_Scenarios